# boost thread and socket

Tags: boost-asio, boost-thread

I have a very weird problem. In server class, if I comment t1.join() I can not read anything from the socket in the HandleFunction. But if I uncomment t1.join(), that works just fine.
But I need this listen function run forever and create a thread to handle the socket whenever it accept one. If i add join there will definately create some problem.
How can i fix it?
thanks in advance

```
class server
{
  io_service;
  acceptor;
  void listen()
  {
  for(;;)
  {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    socketPtr = &socket;
    acceptor.accept(socket);
    HandleClass objHandleClass;
    boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&HandleClass::HandleFunction, &objHandleClass, boost::ref(socketptr)));
    //t1.join();
  }
  }
}

int main()
{
  server objServer;
  objServer.listen();
}

class HandleClass
{
  HandleFunction(socket* socketPtr)
  {
    //read from this socket;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop inside `void listen()`

```
for(;;)
  {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    socketPtr = &socket;
    acceptor.accept(socket);
    HandleClass objHandleClass;
    boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&HandleClass::HandleFunction, &objHandleClass, boost::ref(socketptr)));
    //t1.join();
  }
```

Your `socket` object will go out of scope and be destroyed every iteration of this loop, this is why you cannot read from the socket when `t1.join()` is commented out.

Comment: Thank you Sam. It seems to be this problem.

Comment: One more question. How do I put a new Socket created in this loop into a vector outside this loop? Since socket is noncopyable, I cant put it into the vector. And I cant put the pointer into vector because the object will be destroyed and the pointer will point to garbage.

Comment: @cynic the idiomatic solution for socket lifetime is to use `std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>` or `boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>`.